# Is f(x,y)= $(x^2+y^2)^\frac{1}{2}$ not diferrentiable?(and my try)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

If you define f(x,y)= $(x^2+y^2)^\frac{1}{2}$

Then $$f^\prime_x= \frac{x}{f(x,y)}$$and $f^\prime_y= \frac {y}{f(x,y)}$

Now is used the definition of the partials on (0,0) $f^\prime_x= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {h-0}{h}=1$ 
$f^\prime_x= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(0,0+h)-f(0,0)}{h}= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {h-0}{h}=1$

Now to test differentiability

$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac {f(x,y)-f(0,0)- f^\prime_x Δx - f^\prime_y Δy}{(Δx^2+Δy^2)^(\frac{1}{2})}=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac {(x^2+y^2)^(\frac{1}{2})-0-x-y}{(x^2+y^2)^(\frac{1}{2})}$

Note the partials are set to 1.now I don't know if it can  set to any path on differentiability I know it can be done on function,is possible to set a path on any limit?tell me in the questions bellow, but I am going to evaluate as it is possible to set a path.

To y=x

$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac {(2)^(\frac{1}{2})x-2x}{(2)^(\frac{1}{2})x}=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} 1-(2)^(\frac{1}{2})= 1-(2)^(\frac{1}{2}) $

Now setting another path y=-x

$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac {(2)^(\frac{1}{2})x-0}{(2)^(\frac{1}{2})x}=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} 1=1 $

If it was a function I would say as we approach f from different paths to origin we obtain different values hence discontinuous.not sure what to say next,but something like not diferrentiable.

If is true then even though the function as partials on point (0,0) and the function is continuous as easily notice the function is not diferentiable on (0,0) hence not diferrentiable.is this true? I thought if a functions was continuous and its partials exit was diferrentiable.

As a reminder I am asking 3 questions.(path on diferentiabillity?conclusion of last question? And no differentiability)

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{h^2}=|h|$, so the function has no partial derivative at $(0,0)$, because $(f(0+h,0)-f(0,0))/h=|h|/h$.

Comment: Are you implying that h is positive or negative in the partials ? I don't it is right because is only can be done in $y^2=x^2$ hence y=+-x @egreg

Comment: One should make no particular assumption about $h$, other than $h\ne0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit to compute for the partial derivative with respect to $x$ at $(0,0)$ is
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{h^2}}{h}
=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{|h|}{h}
$$
which doesn't exist. Therefore $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

The fact is that $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$.

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't exist. Can you elaborate on that?please.maybe in your answer

Comment: @KellyBlunie The limit from the right is $1$, the limit from the left is $-1$.

Comment: so is true that a continuous function on a point and the the partials exist on that point is said to be differentiable at that point? and if is true to all points then it is differrentiable?

Comment: @KellyBlunie No. There are functions continuous at a point $P$, with partial derivatives at $P$, but that are not differentiable at $P$.

Comment: thanks for your help I apreciated